# How to Set Up Specific Active Record Association

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to Rails and working with databases, and am wondering what the best way to set up the following Active Record Association would be.

I have the following tables:

- user
- product
- request

I need each table to relate to the other tables in the following manner:

- Every user should be able to have many products. Products will belong to users.
- The products table needs to be associated with the user table in a way that no request is necessary to access product data through an association with user data
- Every request needs to have two users, defined by foreign keys as requester and requestee
- Every request also needs to have two products, defined as requester_product and requestee_product

I initially thought I could use a has_many :through association (seen here under 2.4: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association), but this structure won't allow accessing product data through user data without the existence of a request.

Comment: How are users associated with products without a request? Or do you just want a list of products without having to find the request object?

Comment: An early step for users in the application is to add products that will be associated with their account. So every user will have many products. Requests can then be sent from any user to any other user to exchange products. Each request will then have two users and two products, as mentioned above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :requests
  has_many :products

end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :requests
  belongs_to :users

end

class Request < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :requester, class_name: 'User'
  belongs_to :requestee, class_name: 'User'
  belongs_to :requester_product, class_name: 'Product'
  belongs_to :request_product, class_name: 'Product'

end
```

I've assumed that multiple users can be associated with multiple products. Giving you:

```
user.products
product.user
request.requester # will return the relevant requesting user
request.requestee # will return the relevant requestee user
request.requester_product # will return the relevant requesting user's product
request.requestee_product # will return the relevant requestee user's product
product.requests # all requests associated to a product
user.requests # all requests associated to a user
```

Comment: Thank you! Only thing is that every product should only be associated with one user. I'm guessing that would just change the second line in the user class?

Comment: OK. If each product can only be associated to one user then it turns into a `has_many` in the `User` model and `belongs_to` in the `Product` model.

Comment: If the Product can only have 1 User associated to it, then you do not even need to associate Users to the request.  You can obtain the request Users via the Product.